# Why does the part after `$` disappear when an RStudio snippet is entered?

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

I created the following snippet:

```
snippet setttwd
    setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
```

[image]

But when I type `setttwd` and press enter, I get the following piece of code:

[image]

Note that `$path` has disappeared.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because $ is used as a special character to denote where the cursor
> should jump after completing each section of a snippet, in order to
> insert a literal $ it must be escaped as \$.

https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_snippets.html#customizing-snippets

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `$` by `\$` solved the issue

```
snippet setttwd
    setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()\$path))
```